# Youtube Thumbnails breaking on maxres use

Tags: html, node.js, youtube-api, angular-cli

Does youtube not allow you to pull thumbnails from channelids / playlists with the highest quality images?

Currently, I'm using Nodejs/angular-cli to pull yt thumbnails from channel ids, but when I edit this file to get maxresdefaults to display, it breaks the functionality.

changing

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img [src]="video.thumbnails.high.url" height="auto" width="auto" /> 
<h4>hqdefault</h4>
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img [src]="video.thumbnails.maxres.url" height="auto" width="auto" /> 
<h4>maxresdef</h4>
```

— doesn't work, any suggestions/clarity?

So I would have to imagine youtube doesn't allow Maxres being pulled from channel id thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Resources of the same type may still have different thumbnail image sizes for certain images depending on the resolution of the original image or content uploaded to YouTube. For example, an HD video may support higher resolution thumbnails than non-HD videos.

also

> maxres -  object -
>   The highest resolution version of the thumbnail image. This image size is available for some videos and other resources that refer to videos, like playlist items or search results. This image is 1280px wide and 720px tall.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails

In short, channels don't explicitly support maxres images.